# h3c switch - get which trunk group that a port belongs to via SNMP

Tags: switch, snmp, snmpv3

**Switch**: HP FF 12900 with JG857A, JG626A and JG623A modules

I want to get which trunk group a port is belongs to via SNMP on my h3c core switch. Which MIB and OID can I use to get that data via SNMP?

A couple of years back we had a HP core switch (which has been replaced by a h3c swtich). We have a script that takes a MAC address and starts at the core switch and tries to figure out which port on a access switch the MAC address is present at. Most of the OID used via SNMP works for the h3c  switch but the `1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.7.1.3.1.1.8` OID (`hpSwitchPortTrunkGroup`) does not work for the h3c switch and I can't find another OID which could be used instead.

Comment: You're not specifying which H3C switch you're using - the corresponding MIBs should be available on HPE support.

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks, I have added the switch model and the installed modules now.

Comment: Have you tried those https://serverfault.com/questions/540507/get-port-vlan-tag-via-snmp-on-hp-procurve ?